# How to assert a negative fact in Pyke?

Tags: python, declarative, pyke

Let's say I have fact file:

```
code_in_git(a)
code_in_git(b)
code_in_git(c)
build_on_disk(a)
build_on_disk(c)
```

I want to assert the rule "*if code_in_git($branch) and not build_on_disk($branch), create fact needs_build($branch)*". How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, seems I can assert them with `notany`:

```
no_build_on_disk
    foreach
        deploy.code_in_git($branch)
        notany
            deploy.build_on_disk($branch)
    assert
        deploy.needs_build($branch)
```